# AlertDialog.Builder.show() vs AlertDialog.show() in Android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

What is the main difference between creating an AlertDialog and then showing and showing the AlertDialog.Builder itself?

For example. I can have a AlertDialog.Builder like this:

```
 AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
   dialogBuilder.setTitle("title");
   dialogBuilder.setMessage("message");
   dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
```

And I can show it in two ways:

Just showing the builder

```
dialogBuilder.show();
```

or create an AlertDialog from the builder and then show it

```
AlertDialog dialog = dialogBuilder.create();
dialog.show();
```

Comment: Calling the `create` method within the builder means that you can further customize the dialog itself since you will get the reference of the dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both does the same thing internally

`dialogBuilder.show()` this will create a dialog and call `show()` on the dialog as below

```
public AlertDialog show() {
        final AlertDialog dialog = create();
        dialog.show();
        return dialog;
    }
```

whereas `dialog.show()` directly invokes `show()` method of dialog since dialog is already created

Answer (score 0):

```
obj.create()-For create Dialog
```

`obj.show()`-For show Dialog <- without it you cant show dialog if you created.

and

`obj.create().show()`-create and show Dialog i mean both same as above two in one statement.

and you can also reffer [android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)